# Are themes visible at design time?

Tags: asp.net, themes

This is my first experience with themes.

I've created a skin file for a textbox and the defined theme is only visible at runtime.

Is this the way theme works or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `StylesheetTheme` property that can be set on page level or globally

**Page Level**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" StylesheetTheme="MyTheme" %>
```

**Global (web.config)**

```
<system.web>
  <pages styleSheetTheme="MyTheme" />
<system.web>
```